# Scala: Grouping on the basis of inner list of objects

Tags: scala, generics

I have list of objects like:

```
      [
        {
        studentId: "a1",
        std: "10",
        isEligible:True,
        completedProjectInfo: [
        {
           projectNumber: "c1",
           projectName: "AAT",
           projectCompletedPlaces: {
             count:2,
             city:["Mumbai", "Delhi"]
           }
        }
        ]
       },
       {
        studentId: "a2",
        std: "10",
        isEligible:false,
        completedProjectInfo: [
        {
           projectNumber: "c3",
           projectName: "AAK",
           projectCompletedPlaces: {
             count:1,
             city:["Mumbai"]
           }
        }
        ]
       },
       {
        studentId: "a3",
        std: "10",
        isEligible:false,
        completedProjectInfo: [
        {
           projectNumber: "c3",
           projectName: "AAK",
           projectCompletedPlaces: {
             count:1,
             city:["Mumbai"]
           }
        }
        ]
        },
{
    studentId: "a4",
    std: "10",
    isEligible:true,
    completedProjectInfo: [
   {
       projectNumber: "c1",
       projectName: "AAT",
       projectCompletedPlaces: {
         count:2,
         city:["Mumbai", "Delhi"]
       }
    },
    {
       projectNumber: "c3",
       projectName: "AAK",
       projectCompletedPlaces: {
         count:1,
         city:["Mumbai"]
       }
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
```

Now I want to make groups of students with the exact same info like with above data student result should be something like this:

```
[
  {
        commonInfoStudents: [a2, a3],
        std: "10",
        isEligible:false,
        completedProjectInfo: [
        {
           projectNumber: "c3",
           projectName: "AAK",
           projectCompletedPlaces: {
             count:1,
             city:["Mumbai"]
           }
        }
        ]
    
  },
  {
        commonInfoStudents: ["a1"],
        std: "10",
        isEligible:True,
        completedProjectInfo: [
        {
           projectNumber: "c1",
           projectName: "AAT",
           projectCompletedPlaces: {
             count:2,
             city:["Mumbai", "Delhi"]
           }
        }
        ]
  },
   {
      commonInfoStudents: ["a4"],
      std: "10",
    isEligible:true,
    completedProjectInfo: [
   {
       projectNumber: "c1",
       projectName: "AAT",
       projectCompletedPlaces: {
         count:2,
         city:["Mumbai", "Delhi"]
       }
    },
    {
       projectNumber: "c3",
       projectName: "AAK",
       projectCompletedPlaces: {
         count:1,
         city:["Mumbai"]
       }
    }
    ]
   }
]
```

I tried few things with groupBy, I can group by with std and isEligible but don't understand how to compare inner objects.

Anyone can help here?
thank you.

Comment: Note: the name of the language is "Scala". "SCALA" is a completely different product from IBM.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about comparing lists, you just compare them same way as all other objects.

```
    list
     .groupMap(_.copy(studentId=0))(_.studentId)
     .map { case (data, ids) => data.copy(commonInfoStudents=ids) }
```